# SelectedValue vs SelectedItem.Value of DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I'm working on an old project written and then patched by several people over the years. At some places they have used SelectedValue property and other places they used SelectedItem.Value.

**Question:** Is `SelectedValue` just a *syntactic sugar* for `SelectedItem.Value` or `SelectedValue` works differently under the hood? Which one performs better?

**Edit:** SelectedItem.Text was replaced with SelectedItem.Value

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`SelectedValue` returns the same value as `SelectedItem.Value`.

`SelectedItem.Value` and `SelectedItem.Text` might have different values and the performance is not a factor here, only the meanings of these properties matters.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlUserTypes">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Admins" Value="1" Selected="true" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Users" Value="2"/>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here, `ddlUserTypes.SelectedItem.Value == ddlUserTypes.SelectedValue` and both would return the value "1".

`ddlUserTypes.SelectedItem.Text` would return "Admins", which is different from `ddlUserTypes.SelectedValue`

**edit**

under the hood, SelectedValue looks like this

```
public virtual string SelectedValue
{
    get
    {
        int selectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            return this.Items[selectedIndex].Value;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

and SelectedItem looks like this:

```
public virtual ListItem SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        int selectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            return this.Items[selectedIndex];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

One major difference between these two properties is that the `SelectedValue` has a *setter* also, since `SelectedItem` doesn't. The *getter* of `SelectedValue` is faster when writing code, and the problem of execution performance has no real reason to be discussed. Also a big advantage of SelectedValue is when using Binding expressions.

**edit** data binding scenario (you can't use SelectedItem.Value)

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategories" runat="server" 
                       SelectedValue='<%# Eval("CategoryId")%>'>
     </asp:DropDownList>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out.. I mistakenly typed .Text.. actually .Value is being used everywhere. So, the inner implementation of both properties (SelectedItem.Value & SelectedValue) are same? Isn't SelectedItem (two dots) syntax more complex compared to one-hop-away SelectedValue?

Comment: Thank you Adrian. Can you detail about the Binding expressions advantage? Would be very obliged!

Comment: @vulcanraven, welcome, I updated the answer with a databinding example

Comment: I'm not sure that your "under the hood" section is correct. I just discovered that the `SelectedItem` will return you an item selected based on its value, not the index. This means if you have multiple items with the same `Value`, its possible that `SelectedItem` returns the wrong one.

Comment: I used Reflector to see it

Answer (score 9):

One important distinction between the two (which is visible in the Reflected code) is that SelectedValue will return an empty string if a nothing is selected, whereas SelectedItem.Value will throw a NullReference exception.

Answer (score 4):

They are both different. `SelectedValue` property gives you the actual value of the item in selection whereas `SelectedItem.Text` gives you the display text. For example: you drop down may have an itme like

```
<asp:ListItem Text="German" Value="de"></asp:ListItem>
```

So, in this case `SelectedValue` would be `de` and `SelectedItem.Text` would give 'German'

**EDIT:**

In that case, they aare both same ... Cause `SelectedValue` will give you the value stored for current selected item in your dropdown and `SelectedItem.Value` will be Value of the currently selected item.

So they both would give you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In droupDown list there are two item add property.

1) Text
2) value

If you want to get text property then u use selecteditem.text

and If you want to select value property then use selectedvalue property

In your case i thing both value and text property are the same so no matter if u use selectedvalue or selecteditem.text

If both are different then they give us different results

Comment: This comment is confusing.  Yes, selectedValue property and selectedItem.Text CAN be the same, but VERY frequently they are NOT as per example above where SelectedValue is "de" and SelectedItem.Text is "German"  or  SelectedValue is "CA" and  SelectedItem.Text is "California".  Most commonly,  SelectedValue is the string representation of a DB primary index value and SelectedItem.Text is value from a specific column for the same row in a DB table.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using SelectedItem.Text...
If there is no item selected, then SelectedItem will be null and SelectedItem.Text will generate a null-value exception.

.NET should have provided a SelectedText property like the SelectedValue property that returns String.Empty when there is no selected item.