# access query no result

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Can some one tell me what is wrong with this query as I run this query and refer combo box value on the form but it is not returning any value?

```
SELECT  [2G_KPI].CSSR
FROM 2G_KPI
WHERE ((([2G_KPI].CSSR) Like [Forms]![Form1]![segment_name].[Text]));
```

Comment: It is not returning any results because none of the rows satisfy the `where` condition.

Comment: the record exist but if i manually put the values then it return but if i refer to combo then it dont

Answer (score 0):

In ComboBox you there are 3 things, selectedValue , SelectedIndex and Selected text
Based on how you have coded,debug and check what value goes in the "predicate of your where clause".

Comment: what is the difference between selected text and selected index, one return text and other return index and how selected value differ from them?

Comment: Please refer this url.                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564024/selectedvalue-vs-selecteditem-value-of-dropdownlist