# Is it better to set the SelectedValue of a drop-down list or to set the Selected property of the specific item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownbox

For asp.net dropdownlist, both of the below lines of code achieve the same thing. The only difference I see is one is shorter than other. Is there a specific advantage of using one over the other other than code readability?

```
ddl.SelectedValue = 5;
```

vs.

```
ddl.Items.FindByValue(5).Selected = True;
```

Comment: Look at the link below it might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564024/selectedvalue-vs-selecteditem-value-of-dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both items do most of the same things; however, the second line, if no item is found, will throw an exception:

```
ddl.Items.FindByValue(5) //may return null..
                        .Selected = True; //throws NullReferenceException
```

Whereas selectedvalue doesn't provide that hassle.